# Unlock_instructions email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, unlock

i am using the devise for my User account where i will get all the confirmation, user password instructions etc; 
But i am having a condition where if user account is locked (where status is false in my scenario), he has to get a reset password link through email. This locking process is coded in other controller so we cannot use devise helpers.

my controller code:

> def send_instruction
>
> a=[]
>
> ```
> if @answer1
>   a << '1'
> end
> if @answer2
>   a <<   '2'
> end
> if @answer3
>   a <<  '3'
> end
>
> if a.size <= 1
>
>    SiteMailer.unlock_user(current_user).deliver
>
>   current_user.update_attribute(:status,false)
>
>   destroy_user_session_path(current_user)
>
>   flash[:error]= "Your account is locked"
>
>   redirect_to new_user_session_path
>
>  else
>
>   redirect_to user_dashboard_path
>
> end
> ```

mailers/site_mailer.rb:

> class SiteMailer < ActionMailer::Base
>
> include Devise::Mailers::Helpers
>
> default from: "support@example.com"
>        def unlock_user(user)
>
> ```
> @user = user
>
> @url = "pwd_edit"
>
> mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Your account has been locked')
> ```
>
> end
>
> end

in mailer view:

> ## Hi,
>
> Your account with  has been locked. Edit Profile:
>   "My link (edit_user_password_url(current_user)".

When i am going through this process, I am getting "No routes found" error. And my routes are correct. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because no `current_user` is present at that time. You should try this instead

```
edit_user_password_url(@user)
```

Comment: If i want to use reset password tokens like devise, is there any alternative or can we customize in my controller method?

Comment: Got it.. i just removed my SiteMailer and added the step:   **current_user.send_reset_password_instructions**